# mkdir.exe invalid option -- f in Netbeans

Tags: c++, windows, netbeans

I can't compile a C++ program in Netbeans. I get the error

> "C:/MinGW/msys/1.0/bin/mkdir.exe": invalid option -- f
>
> Try `"C:/MinGW/msys/1.0/bin/mkdir.exe" --help' for more information.
>
> COMPILE FILE FAILED (exit value 1, total time: 1s)

When I try to run mkdir from command line with that flag --f, I get the same error, so maybe the option that Netbeans is trying to use doesn't exist for my Msys version, although I think it's the most current.
Thank you.

Comment: search for  `--f` in your makefile and post relevant part.

Answer (score 0):

Not a full solution but maybe it will help to bypass the problem.

Rename the old `mkdir.exe` to some other name, and create new text file in the directory and name it `mkdir.exe.bat`.

In the new file just write: `mkdir %2` to skip the first argument.

as long as all mkdirs are running the same command it should work.

I hope it will help